# Interfaces, generics, and covariant return types

Tags: java, generics, interface, covariant

Suppose I have an interface as follows:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    T doSomething();
}
```

Now, are both the following allowed?

```
public class Bar implements Foo<Number> { ... }

public class Bar2 extends Bar implements Foo<Integer> { ... }
```

On one hand, I seem to not think so, since `Bar2` "implements `Foo` twice", even though `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`.  On the other hand, wouldn't this be a case of covariant return type on `doSomething()`?  Or is the compiler not smart enough to detect as such?

Comment: "_Now, are both the following allowed?_" Can't you just try to run these things and see?

Comment: `Foo<T>` must be an `interface` not a `class`

Comment: I dont know why this question is having negative vote? Man this question is clearing my concepts.

Answer (score 2):

If `Foo` is meant to be an interface:

> A class may not at the same time be a subtype of two interface types which are different parameterizations of the same generic interface [...], or a compile-time error occurs.

So no. ([JLS 8.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5))

And it would not really make sense anyway because you would be downcasting whatever `Bar` happens to return from `doSomething`. Maybe it's a `Double`.

On the other hand, you may still do:

```
class Bar2 extends Bar {
    @Override
    public Integer doSomething() {...}
}
```

> Or is the compiler not smart enough to detect as such?

What we and the compiler think doesn't matter here. The compiler is bound to the language specification which dictates an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an interface, it seems to be a class(or abstract class which is also missing the keyword `abstract`), it should be like:-

```
public interface Foo<T> {
        T doSomething();
}
```

Besides

```
public class Bar implements Foo<Number> { ... }

public class Bar2 extends Bar implements Foo<Integer> { ... }
```

Will give you compile time error , 
`The interface Foo cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: Foo<Number> and Foo<Integer>`

But if you instead do :-

```
public class Bar implements Foo<Integer> { ... }

public class Bar2 extends Bar implements Foo<Integer> { ... }
```

This will not give an compile time error, and if you implement `doSomething()` in Bar2 it will take that into consideration when you do :-

```
Bar2 bar2=new Bar2();
bar2.doSomething();
```

or else it will run the `doSomething()` from `Bar`

and obviously if you do:-

```
Bar bar=new Bar();
bar.doSomething();
```

it will take into consideration `doSomething()` of `Bar` , since it does have only one implemented `doSomething()` into account this time , i.e of `Bar`(which you have to implement since `Bar` is implementing the interface `Foo` :) )